# window.location.href not working after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, razorpay

In this code I am using `razorpay` payment gateway api where payments are successfully done but not able to redirect after success ajax call. So, How can I redirect page using `window.location.href` in order page? Please help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buy_now').click(function(e) {
    var total_amount = $(".total_amount").val();
    var product_id = $(".product_id").map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get().join(",");
    var new_uid = $("#new_uid").val();
    var user_id = $("#uid").val();
    var user_email = $(".user_email").attr("id");
    var options = {
      "key": "************************",
      "amount": (1 * 100), // 2000 paise = INR 20
      "name": "MyApp",
      "description": "Payment",
      "image": "https://www.MyApp.com/img/logo/logo.png",
      "handler": function(response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>razorPaySuccess',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            "razorpay_payment_id": response.razorpay_payment_id,
            "total_amount": total_amount,
            "product_id": product_id,
            "new_uid": new_uid,
            "user_email": user_email,
            "user_id": user_id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>order";
          }
        });
      },
      "theme": {
        "color": "#528FF0"
      }
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: The line which performs the redirect looks fine, which probably means that the AJAX request isn't working and you instead need to debug that, not the redirectl.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `failed()` to your ajax request or even the `error` to see why it's failing from the api. Read more on jquery ajax here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Store your url in a variable then call this line.

```
var url = "your current url";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why exactly does anybody need an additional variable for this? Does this alone help, or does the second line make it work?

Comment: The second line is also work alone

$(location).attr('href',"https://www.google.com");

and you should enter the complete url thats you want.

Answer (score 0):

So far i didn't noticed any mistake of your code.. you just make sure that it goes to `success: function()` and use `window.location.replace` not `window.location.href`. So it will replace the current url and redirect you to your success page.

```
window.location.replace = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>order";
```

If that code above still don't work. your `e.preventDefault()` can cause you preventing to redirect to your success page so make sure to use it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Do like this:-

```
var path = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
window.location.href = path+"order";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why should adding the URL to a variable first solve the problem?

Comment: like we using php code in jquery so it's better to store that value to in variable to we access it later and also can check or manipulate it better as per our use. and also direct accessing php code into jquery will not allow customization. this is my thought, but you can tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: But can you tell the difference between the original code and yours? Is there any significant one, cause I can't see any

Comment: no there no much difference but i have just assign to variable other change was depend on api response that user can get then based on that have to make changes.

Comment: Ok, so using your answer does not solve the problem then?

Answer (score -2):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href; it may work for you.
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.